# Javascript async defer order of execution in case of multiple files in Single Page Applications

Tags: javascript, html, performance, asynchronous, deferred

I am trying to improve the page load performance of my page, that is implemented on EmberJS.

I am considering using `asyc` and `defer` on our Javascript files. All other optimizations have already been done (moving the scripts to the bottom of the page, adding `async` and `defer` to analytics tags etc).

Now, as per `ember-cli` specs, the generated `index.html` has two script tags - one vendor JS file and one application JS file.

If I am to implement `async` and `defer`, I need to ensure that my vendor JS file is loaded *before* my application JS file, to make sure the latter has all required code to initialize the application.

I understand that the order in which the scripts are fetched and parsed are different when defined with `async` and `defer`, as defined [here](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/speed-up-google-maps-and-everything-else-with-async-defer-7b9814efb2b#.v77i9d7lx)

[image]

My question is this:

#### If you have multiple JS files in the same page, is there a way to fetch and execute them in a stipulated order? I'm looking for something like callbacks/promises in async requests, but in terms of the actual `script` tag itself.

Answer (score 7):

Things may have changed for the better since this question was first posted, but it seems that in 2019 you can defer your scripts and have them processed ***in the order the script tags are written in your html document***. Adding `defer` to both your `vendor` script and your `main` script will cause them to load in parallel, not block parsing of the html document, and be processed **in order** on document parse completion.

The [4.12.1.1 Processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model) section of whatwg's scripting document goes into quite a bit of detail that I'll try to summarise here:

- If the script's type is "classic" (not `type="module"`), and the element has a `src` attribute, and the element has a `defer` attribute, and the element has been flagged as "parser-inserted", and the element does not have an `async` attribute
- then add the element to the end of ***the list of scripts that will
  execute in order as soon as possible*** associated with the node
  document of the script element at the time the prepare a script
  algorithm started.

Check out the link for full details, but essentially what it seems to be saying is that deferred scripts will be processed in the order they are parsed in the html document.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) agrees:

> Scripts with the `defer` attribute will execute in the order in which
> they appear in the document.

One other important point to note (from the same MDN document):

> Scripts with the `defer` attribute will prevent the `DOMContentLoaded` event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.

It's also worth noting that neither whatwg nor MDN says anything about placing your script tag in the head or at the bottom of the body of the html document. If all of your scripts have the `defer` attribute, they will be processed in occurrence order when the html document has completed parsing. Putting the script tags in the header will mean they will start to download early in the html document parsing process, rather than later which is the case when they are placed at the bottom of the body. But of course that also depends on how many other resources you are downloading from the same host in parallel.

Rambling a bit now, but in summary, for best non-blocking performance:

- Place all your script tags as early in the html document as possible
- Add them in the order that you want them to be processed
- Add the `defer` attribute to all of them (if they don't need to be processed synchronously or as soon as downloaded)
- For scripts that need to be processed as soon as downloaded, add the `async` attribute. HTML parsing will continue while the script is downloading - will pause when the script has finished downloading and while the script is executed - and will resume once the script has finished executing.
- For scripts that need to be processed as soon as downloaded, and that have side effects such as modifying the DOM, don't add `async` or `defer`. HTML parsing will pause while the script is downloading - will stay paused when the script has finished downloading and while the script is executed - and will resume once the script has finished executing.

**Update July 2020:**

In Chrome, downloading and parsing of synchronous scripts (those without `async` or `defer`) has improved quite a bit. Downloading and parsing are done on separate threads - and the download thread streams the file into the parser as it downloads.

In combination with [`<link rel="preload">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) in your `<head>`, it's possible that your file could be downloaded by the time the HTML parser reaches your `<script>` tag - which means it won't need to pause and can execute the script right away:

[image: Better downloading and parsing of synchronous scripts]

The image above is taken from the video [Day 2: Chrome web.dev Live 2020 - What's New in V8 / Javascript](https://youtu.be/TPm-UhWkiq8?t=242) - the section in which they explain updates to downloading and parsing is about 4 minutes long, but well worth the watch.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches.

a) Do what you said. i.e. have a script tag which has two chained promises inside, each of which creates a new script tag, appends it to the DOM, adds an `onload` event function which would be the promise's `resolve` function and lastly sets its `src` attribute to the resource's URL. When the  script from the first promise loads, the second promise should execute and do the same thing.

b) Take the middle road. Have the vendor file in the head, to load synchronously, and have the application file at the very bottom of the document, to load after everything else finished.

In my opinion the first option is an overkill.

EDIT: Example for a)

```
<script>
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
    scriptTag.onload = resolve;
    scriptTag.src = 'URL_to_vendor_file';
});

p.then(function() {
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
    scriptTag.src = 'URL_to_application_file';
};
</script>
```

Note: The example above can be written and without the use of promises

Comment: `1.` Having promises will require polyfills because of browser support. So it might end up causing more sluggishness than it's trying to prevent.



`2.` I'm not sure how much performance upgrade this will achieve because this way, the browser will need to parse the entire vendor JS file before getting to DOM construction. Adding both vendor and app at the bottom of the body tag might be ore beneficial than this, don't you think? Especially if vendor JS > app JS in size

Comment: What you said about promises is true, that's why I noted you can do that with no promises at all, just set the onload function of the first script tag to be the callback of the .then promise.  I am not sure in general if what you are trying to do here has that much value at all. I mean, if you use ember do you even have that much of an HTML document? Unless you are doing server side rendering I assume you don't. You are in the area of micro optimizations IMO

Comment: Also, remind me, why can you not put both the vendor and app scripts at the end? What is the limitation here?

Comment: Wouldn't putting both scripts at the end, vendor first, achieve exactly what you want though? Your dom parsing would not get blocked. If the load order of the rest of the scripts does not matter (vendor has to load first for sure I assume) then maybe you can add async to them.